# Linux Mint corrupted display, on first run in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, linux-mint, boot

Today I tried to install Linux Mint to test my programs on it. When I run Linux Mint from my .iso file I get this: [image: an image of virtual box running Mint, with a corrupted display: lots of random colours rectangles, of the same size. It has a horizontal stripy appearance, and there is horizontal alternating repetition.]
So I don't know what should I do. My pc has Intel Core I3 x64, Radeon r7 240 and it works fine with everything. Linux Mint 18.3 cinnamon-32bit

Comment: What do they (Harvard) mean by an appliance?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu distribution with plugin for default text editor which can compile C code.

Comment: There is also some other stuff for testing your code for right solution.

Comment: Ah so Ubuntu + custom Harvard stuff. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: exactly! Yes, I'm not sure about the reason, it ran after reload.Maybe virtualbox window size matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like window resizing bug, I just reloaded it and made the window full sized.

Comment: This did not work for me... However, since this was the first post I found for my search terms on the Google, I'll share my fix for future visitors. I was able to fix by using `CTRL ALT F1` to enter another console and then install `virtualbox-guest-dkms` and `virtualbox-guest-dkms` packages using Apt. Finally, restarting lightdm loaded the desktop correctly: `systemctl restart lightdm`.

Comment: this seems to be repeated "then install virtualbox-guest-dkms and **virtualbox-guest-dkms**  packages using Apt" other than that you saved me

Comment: For me it helped to first shutdown the VM (click the garbled shutdown icon, then click enter to confirm), Then turn of 3d acceleration in the config
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=354405